# Minimum Android OS version for C++11 support

Tags: android, c++11, android-ndk

I've found some sources that indicate C++11 is only supported on iOS versions 5 and above (such as [this site that says "To use C++11, the minimum ios version is 5.0"](http://blog.worldofcoding.com/2014/05/cross-compiling-c11-without-going-madder.html)).

**I'm wondering if there's any minimum Android OS version that has C++11 support?**

I need to support at least Android version 2.3. My research so far seems to indicate no such min OS level. It would be preferable if anyone could point to official documentation on the issue if there is any (I haven't been able to find it so far).

Comment: I think its less what version of Android OS supports C++11 as what libraries are you are using which aren't available on Android. If the compiler can process C++ and transform it into x86/ARM/MIPS code then it become a library/API problem. For reference the NDK has been available since Android 1.5/1.6 http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/now-available-android-16-ndk.html

Comment: The app that I need to know this for is already available on the android app stores (Play and Amazon). I just want to make sure we don't break our app on older devices by starting to use C++11. What you've said makes sense to me, I just wanted to verify since iOS does (apparently) have a min version that supports C++11. From the sounds of your comment we'll be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android, the C++ standard library shipped with the system is a very limited one - if you actually want a proper, standards conforming C++ standard library, it gets bundled into your application (either linked statically or dynamically, based on the choice in the `APP_STL` variable).

So if you choose to use a C++11 conforming standard library, it's distributed as part of your application, so it should work regardless of the Android platform version.